# foundation modal events are not working

Tags: meteor, zurb-foundation

My code

```
{{#with profile}}

        {{> foundation}}
{{/with}}


<template name="foundation">
    <div id="userprofile" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
         <h2 id="selectedProfileName">{{name}}</h2>
        <div class="large-12 columns paddingtop">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <img id="selectedProfilePicture" src="{{picurl}}" />
                <p id="selectedProfileLink" ><a href="/accounts/profile/{{_id}}" >Open Profile</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns right">
            <div id="btnCancel" class="btnCancel button button-register small">Cancel</div>
            <div id="btnConfirm" class="btnConfirm button button-register small" data={{_id}}>Okay</div>
        </div>      
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm opening the modal using JS

```
$("#userprofile").foundation("reveal","open");
```

My events are

```
Template.foundation.events({
    'click .btnConfirm':function(evt){
        console.log("confirm");
        $('#curator_name').val("");
        $('#confirmationText').html("");
    },
    'click .btnCancel':function(){
        console.log("close");

    },
});
```

They are not firing, anyone faced the same issue.

I tried to put all the modal code in parent template and binding the events, That is also not working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's quite possible that, like Semantic-UI and some other frameworks, Foundation modals are removed from the DOM and programmatically added elsewhere (like at the end of the body).  If this is the case, then event handlers registered on the enclosing template will no longer be able to find them.

The solution is to define a template *within* your modal, and attach the events to that.  Something like:

```
<template name="foundation">
  <div id="userprofile" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    {{> foundationInner}}  
  </div>
</template>

<template name="foundationInner">
  <h2 id="selectedProfileName">{{name}}</h2>
  <div class="large-12 columns paddingtop">
    ...
  </div>      
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</template>
```

Then register all the event handlers on `foundationInner` (which isn't getting moved *relative to its parent view*).

If, of course, there's no detachment and reattachment happening in Foundation, then it's something else entirely.  More on this issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/0Upkyo9F54k).

Answer (score 1):

```
    Template.foundation.rendered = function() {
       // your code to show the modal
       $("#userprofile").foundation("reveal","open");

    }
```